# Write values in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I am trying to loop over a list of dictionaries and write values to this specific dictionary:

```
from model.statistic_model import Sher, Op, Npp

TODAY = "today"
OVERALL = "overall"
SHER = "sherlock"
OP = "oprisk"
NPP = "npp"

popular_search_terms = {SHER: {TODAY: {}, OVERALL: {}}, OP: {TODAY: {}, OVERALL: {}}, NPP: {TODAY: {}, OVERALL: {}}}
engines = [Sher, Op, Npp]   
engines_container_overall = [popular_search_terms[SHER][OVERALL], popular_search_terms[OP][OVERALL], popular_search_terms[NPP][OVERALL]]

try:
    for index, engine in enumerate(engines):
        engines_container_overall[index] = df.get_popular_searchterms(False, engine)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    for index, engine in enumerate(engines):
        engines_container_overall[index] = pd.DataFrame()
```

When I access my list and print the following, I receive the values I want.

```
print(engines_container_overall[0])
```

But If i want to print the values of a specific dict, like **popular_search_terms[SHER][OVERALL]**, the value is none.

How can I successfully add data to a specific dictionary in my list?

Comment: Please, post [mre]. What are `SHER`, `OVERALL` and all other undefined names?

Comment: Also note that in the first dict all names as ALLCAPS, while in the list they are Titled

Comment: Sorry, have added relevant variables

Comment: No, you did not - what is `df`? Nor we know what `model.statistic_model` or what  `Sher`, `Op`, `Npp` are...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do it via the list.
Python only saves a reference to the dictionary in the list.
You can directly modify your dictionary with the `update` function.

Let's say

```
popular_search_terms = {SHER:{OVERALL:{"Test_SHER_overall":20}}}    
print(engines_container_overall[0])
```

produces `{'Test_SHER_overall': 20}`

Now update the dictionary

```
popular_search_terms[SHER][OVERALL].update({"Test_SHER_overall2":21})
```

and `print(engines_container_overall[0])`
produces
`{'Test_SHER_overall': 20, 'Test_SHER_overall2': 21}`

Comment: Thank you. Had to used "extend" instead of .. = ..